# Importing ProxyDroid via GitHub Results in 300+ Compiler Errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, github, compiler-errors

I'm attempting to import the (open) source of ProxyDroid however when I import it from github I'm getting over 300 errors before I do much of anything.

Without going line by line through heaps of code - does anyone know why this might be happening? I've cleaned the project and it does not resolve the issue and I changed the manifest from using API 16 to 17 but that does not resolve the issue as well.

SOURCE:

https://github.com/madeye/proxydroid

ERRORS:

```
AdView cannot be resolved to a type ProxyDroid.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 142    Java Problem
DatabaseField cannot be resolved to a type  DNSResponse.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid/db   line 15 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  AppManager.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 227    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  AppManager.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 225    Java Problem
DatabaseField cannot be resolved to a type  DNSResponse.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid/db   line 13 Java Problem
DatabaseField cannot be resolved to a type  DNSResponse.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid/db   line 11 Java Problem
DatabaseTable cannot be resolved to a type  DNSResponse.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid/db   line 7  Java Problem
Dao cannot be resolved to a type    DNSProxy.java   /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 129    Java Problem
Dao cannot be resolved to a type    DNSProxy.java   /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 138    Java Problem
DataType cannot be resolved to a variable   DNSResponse.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid/db   line 17 Java Problem
OpenHelperManager cannot be resolved    DNSProxy.java   /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 91 Java Problem
OpenHelperManager cannot be resolved    DNSProxy.java   /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 88 Java Problem
DatabaseField cannot be resolved to a type  DNSResponse.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid/db   line 17 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 132    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 106    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 153    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 150    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 147    Java Problem
OpenHelperManager cannot be resolved    DNSProxy.java   /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 150    Java Problem
AdRequest cannot be resolved to a type  ProxyDroid.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 312    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 144    Java Problem
Dao cannot be resolved to a type    DNSProxy.java   /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 242    Java Problem
AdView cannot be resolved to a type ProxyDroid.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 313    Java Problem
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Sherlock').    AndroidManifest.xml /ProxyDroid line 18 Android AAPT Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 212    Java Problem
FlurryAgent cannot be resolved  ProxyDroid.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 284    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 188    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 191    Java Problem
FlurryAgent cannot be resolved  ProxyDroid.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 278    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 213    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 221    Java Problem
AdRequest cannot be resolved to a type  ProxyDroid.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 312    Java Problem
AdView cannot be resolved to a type ProxyDroid.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 310    Java Problem
MenuItem cannot be resolved to a type   BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 160    Java Problem
AdSize cannot be resolved to a variable ProxyDroid.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 303    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 182    Java Problem
AdView cannot be resolved to a type ProxyDroid.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 303    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 185    Java Problem
AdView cannot be resolved to a type ProxyDroid.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 303    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 181    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 380    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 379    Java Problem
JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type Profile.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 140    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 393    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 313    Java Problem
JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type Profile.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 165    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 311    Java Problem
ParseException cannot be resolved to a type Profile.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 167    Java Problem
JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type Profile.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 141    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 362    Java Problem
JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type Profile.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 141    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 306    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 304    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 250    Java Problem
AdView cannot be resolved to a type ProxyDroid.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 406    Java Problem
AdView cannot be resolved to a type ProxyDroid.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 406    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 420    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 431    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 449    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 464    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 408    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 410    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  BypassListActivity.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 418    Java Problem
Context cannot be resolved  RhinoPacScriptParser.java   /ProxyDroid/src/com/btr/proxy/selector/pac  line 125    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  AppManager.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 144    Java Problem
OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper cannot be resolved to a type    DatabaseHelper.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid/db   line 19 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  AppManager.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 148    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  AppManager.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 212    Java Problem
Dao cannot be resolved to a type    DatabaseHelper.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid/db   line 41 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  AppManager.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 213    Java Problem
OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper cannot be resolved to a type    DatabaseHelper.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid/db   line 40 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  AppManager.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 219    Java Problem
Context cannot be resolved to a type    RhinoPacScriptParser.java   /ProxyDroid/src/com/btr/proxy/selector/pac  line 71 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  AppManager.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 223    Java Problem
Dao cannot be resolved to a type    DatabaseHelper.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid/db   line 29 Java Problem
ContextFactory cannot be resolved to a type RhinoPacScriptParser.java   /ProxyDroid/src/com/btr/proxy/selector/pac  line 71 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  AppManager.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 183    Java Problem
Context cannot be resolved  RhinoPacScriptParser.java   /ProxyDroid/src/com/btr/proxy/selector/pac  line 123    Java Problem
Dao cannot be resolved to a type    DatabaseHelper.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid/db   line 50 Java Problem
Context cannot be resolved to a type    RhinoPacScriptParser.java   /ProxyDroid/src/com/btr/proxy/selector/pac  line 117    Java Problem
Dao cannot be resolved to a type    DatabaseHelper.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid/db   line 49 Java Problem
Dao cannot be resolved to a type    DatabaseHelper.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid/db   line 48 Java Problem
Context cannot be resolved  RhinoPacScriptParser.java   /ProxyDroid/src/com/btr/proxy/selector/pac  line 117    Java Problem
ParseException cannot be resolved to a type Profile.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 207    Java Problem
ConnectionSource cannot be resolved to a type   DatabaseHelper.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid/db   line 77 Java Problem
MenuItem cannot be resolved to a type   ProxyDroid.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 930    Java Problem
Dao cannot be resolved to a type    DatabaseHelper.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid/db   line 52 Java Problem
ConnectionSource cannot be resolved to a type   DatabaseHelper.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid/db   line 61 Java Problem
FlurryAgent cannot be resolved  ProxyDroidService.java  /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 471    Java Problem
JSONParser cannot be resolved to a type Profile.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 168    Java Problem
JSONParser cannot be resolved to a type Profile.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 168    Java Problem
FlurryAgent cannot be resolved  ProxyDroidService.java  /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 668    Java Problem
JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type Profile.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 169    Java Problem
JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type Profile.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 169    Java Problem
JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type Profile.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 181    Java Problem
Menu cannot be resolved to a type   ProxyDroid.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 902    Java Problem
JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type Profile.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 173    Java Problem
MenuItem cannot be resolved to a type   AppManager.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 124    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  AppManager.java /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 78 Java Problem
JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type Profile.java    /ProxyDroid/src/org/proxydroid  line 194    Java Problem
```